Exporting the results to Drive using the Export function in GEE app
I am working on a GEE app and need to export the computation results from the app to Drive. I noticed that the Export function only works in the Code Editor interface, and when I call this function through the app, Export does not respond.
The function is below:
var downloadButton = ui.Button({
    label: 'Export',
    onClick: function() {
    var exportTask = Export.image.toDrive({
      image:resultImage,
      description:'CSI_Export_Task',
      fileNamePrefix:'LCC',
      region:collection,
      scale:30,
      crs:'EPSG:4326'
    })},
    style:{
      width:'200px',
      fontSize :'20px'
    }
});

I want to know if GEE app does not support calling the Export function in the GEE app interface. What can I do to solve this issue? Using getURL doesn't work because my results have high spatial and temporal resolution, making it impossible to download via URL.

Apps are anonymous; there's no Drive account associated with them to which you can export.  If you really need to export something large from an app, you'll probably have to write your own, so you can have someone's credentials to use.  But this means you'll have to deal with OAuth yourself too, which is pretty horrible.
